# Customizing material ui autocompete

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the material-UI Autocomplete component in my react app and I want to show a div when hovering on an option from the list (like in the image)

[Show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIFRH.png)

any help with that, please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the renderOption attribute with a Tooltip like this :

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { Button, Tooltip } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Info } from "@material-ui/icons";



export default function ComboBox() {
      const defaultProps = {
        options: top100Films,
        getOptionLabel: option => option.title
      };
    
      return (
        <Autocomplete
          {...defaultProps}
          id="list-option"
          debug
          ListboxComponent={props => <div {...props} />}
          getOptionDisabled={({ year }) => year > 2000}
          renderOption={({ title, year, ...props }) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <Tooltip title={`Too Old ${year}`} placement="bottom">
                  <div>
                    <Button endIcon={<Info />} component="li" {...props} fullWidth>
                      {title} - {year}
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </Tooltip>
              </div>
            );
          }}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label="Broken Disabled Tooltips"
              margin="normal"
              fullWidth
            />
          )}
        />
      );
    }
```